# scrapy'request seems to be redirected

Tags: scrapy

When I am trying to request the URL:

```
http://www.iqiyi.com/v_19rrk4vf0k.html
```

here is spider:

```
class URLredirect(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'urlredirect_spider'
def start_requests(self):
    reqs = []
    url = 'http://www.iqiyi.com/v_19rrk4vf0k.html'
    req = scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers, meta={'url': url})
    reqs.append(req)
    return reqs

def parse(self, response):
    responseURL = response.url
    requestURL = response.meta['url']
    print '''Response's URL: ''', response.url
    print '''Request's  URL: ''', response.meta['url']
    if str(responseURL).__eq__(requestURL):
        print re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>').findall(response.body)[0].decode('utf-8')
    else:
        print '=================================================================================='
        yield scrapy.Request(url=requestURL, headers=headers, meta={'url': requestURL}, callback=self.parse)
```

when I run my program,I get  these result（three results）：

[image]

I am confuse,why this just happen?It seems to be random redirected！

and when I am not using the middleware,I never got the redirected repsonse?
Here is my middleware:

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    REDIS_HOST = 'myip'
    REDIS_PORT = myport
    redisclient = redis.Redis(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)
    DONT_RETRY_ERRORS = (TimeoutError, ConnectionRefusedError, ResponseNeverReceived, ConnectError, ValueError)
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    """
    将request设置为使用代理
    """
    try:
        self.redisclient = redis.Redis(self.REDIS_HOST, self.REDIS_PORT)
        proxy = self.redisclient.srandmember(proxy_key)
        proxyjson = json.loads(proxy)
        ip = proxyjson["ip"]
        # print ip
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % ip

        # Use the following lines if your proxy requires authentication
        proxy_user_pass = "avcspider:aowei123"
        # setup basic authentication for the proxy
        encoded_user_pass = base64.b64encode(proxy_user_pass)
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
    except Exception, ee:
        import logging
        logging.error(ee)
        pass

def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
    """
    处理由于使用代理导致的连接异常 则重新换个代理继续请求
    """
    # print '错误类型', exception.message
    if isinstance(exception, self.DONT_RETRY_ERRORS):
        new_request = request.copy()
        try:
            self.redisclient = redis.Redis(self.REDIS_HOST, self.REDIS_PORT)
            proxy = self.redisclient.srandmember(proxy_key)
            proxyjson = json.loads(proxy)
            ip = proxyjson["ip"]
            new_request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % ip
        except:
            pass
        return new_request
```

Does any wrong message there?Thanks advance！

Answer (score 0):

By the way, my `LOGLEVEL` is `ERROR`, that is why i just get a few information in my console.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper request headers same as the browser does that for that website. My guess is they are redirecting because you are not using any `user-agent`

```
headers = {
    'DNT': '1',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers, meta={'url': url})
```

I am sure they will not redirect now

Comment: eh,I have header,but I just didn't paste it on